# What flexibility does the wild card type give in the type parameter ?

Tags: java, generics

Consider a generic `min` method in a static utility which is meant to return the minimum element in  a set . Why do we need to declare it as

```
 public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T min(Set<? extends T> producerSet)
```

What will be the problem if we instead declare it as

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T min(Set<? extends T> producerSet)
```

What flexibility is the wild card type in the type parameter  giving me here ?

Comment: Drive-by comment: this is probably somewhere in Angelika Langer's generics FAQ because everything is. (When it comes to generics questions that document is mandatory reading.)

Comment: Heck, it's in the generics tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/morefun.html - an example is that if you have the classes `Animal implements Comparable<Animal>`, and `Cat extends Animal`, if you didn't use `? super T` then you couldn't call `min()` on a `List<Cat>` because it'd require that the item type be comparable to exactly itself, while you only need it to be comparable to itself or a supertype.

Answer (score 0):

This covers the case where T is a subclass of an implementor of Comparable. Consider the following:

```
public static class A implements Comparable<A> {

   public int compareTo(A o) {
      return 0;
   }
}
public static class B extends A {}

public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T min(Set<? extends T> producerSet) {
   return null;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   Set<B> set = new HashSet<B>();
   min(set); // incompatible with method signature
}
```